# How do I properly create a regex for String.matches() with escape characters?

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping

I am trying to check if a string of length one is any of the following characters: `"["`, `"\"`, `"^"`, `"_"`, single back-tick `` "`" ``, or `"]"`.

Right now I am trying to accomplish this with the following if statement:

```
if (character.matches("[[\\]^_`]")){
    isValid = false;
}
```

When I run my program I get the following error for the if statement:

> java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: null (in
>   java.util.regex.Pattern)

What is the correct syntax for a regex with escape characters?

Comment: Escape your character with \. In your statement you're only escaping one \.

Comment: Essentially for every \ you need another one. Double the number of \'s in the regex

Comment: So it should look like this: newChar.matches("[\\[\\\\]\\^\\_\\`]")    ?

Comment: Sorry, like this: matches("[\\[\\\\]\\^\\_\\`]")  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `[`, `]` and `\\` - the `[` and `]` so that the pattern compiler knows that they are not the special character class delimiters, and `\\` because it's already being converted to one backslash because it's in a string literal, so to represent an escaped backslash in a pattern, you need to have no less than four consecutive backslashes.

So the resulting regex should be

```
"[\\[\\]\\\\^_`]"
```

(Test it on [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/ddnuv6) - click on the "Java" button to test).

Answer (score 2):

Your list has four characters that need special attention:

- `^` is the inversion character. It must not be the first character in a character class, or it must be escaped.
- `\` is the escape character. It must be escaped for direct use.
- `[` starts a character class, so it must be escaped.
- `]` ends a character class, so it must be escaped.

Here is the "raw" regex:

```
[\[\]_`\\^]
```

Since you represent your regex as a Java string literal, all backslashes must be additionally escaped for the Java compiler:

```
if (character.matches("[\\[\\]_`\\\\^]")){
    isValid = false;
}
```